# Swift Parse - Nested Calls Issue

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

In my app, I need to load user details in different view controllers. The details I load are not necessarily of the user that is currently signed in (which could be retrieved from currentUser, but sometimes are of other users depending on scenario.

So far I find myself whenever presented with the above need, I do two queries: First to load the details (e.g. name, phone, address, etc.) and second to load the profile image of that user.

So I end up with a nested call such as the below:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")

query.whereKey("appUsername", equalTo: self.friendObject.username!)

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results, error) -> Void in
    let data = results as [PFObject]!
    if(error == nil)
    {
        self.friendObject.name = data[0]["name"] as? String
        self.friendObject.profilePic = data[0]["ProfilePic"] as? UIImage
        self.nameLabel.text = self.friendObject.name
        self.friendObject.objectId = data[0].objectId! as String
        self.getProfilePicture(self.friendObject.username!) { (result)->Void in

             self.profilePicImageView.image = result
        }

    }else{
        print("Error retrieving user details - try again")
    }
}
```

and here is the definition of the getProfilePicture function:

```
func getProfilePicture(username: String, completion: (result: UIImage) -> Void)
    {
        var tempImage:UIImage? = UIImage(named: "sample-qr-code.png")!
        let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        query.whereKey("appUsername", equalTo: username)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            for object in objects! {
               if(object["ProfilePic"] != nil)
               {
                let imageFiles = object["ProfilePic"] as! PFFile
                imageFiles.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        tempImage = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                        let temp2Image: UIImage = Toucan(image: tempImage!).resize(CGSize(width: 100, height: 150)).maskWithEllipse(borderWidth: 3, borderColor: UIColor.whiteColor()).image
                            completion(result: temp2Image)
                    }
                 })
               }else{
                let invalidImage = UIImage(named: "Contacts-100.png")
                completion(result: invalidImage!)
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

The ProfilePic column in the User parse class is of File type. How can I optimize this so that I only do one call to load image and details (given that requests should be minimized as much as possible).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Make your `imageView` a `PFImageView` and then you can set the appropriate file of the `PFImageView` like `self.friendObject.profilePic = data[0]["ProfilePic"] as? PFFile` and then you can do `self.profilePicImageView.file = self.friendObject.profilePic` and then `self.profilePicImageView.loadInBackground`

Comment: the loadInBackground will not trigger a request?

Comment: If by request you mean a request that will count against your Parse requests, then yes it will, but so will the method you've shown.

Comment: Yes indeed and that's why I wanted to know if there is a way to reduce the request...what I see in your recommendation is a different approach rather than a minimization of requests.

Comment: Well there is no way to do this without a request, and yes the way I demonstrated is a different approach but it's also safer and more optimized than what you've written.

Comment: and thank you for sharing the well-written code which I will use but this is really unfortunate that there is no other way around it. I am very worried about the limit of requests

Comment: I think you'll find that the amount of requests end up being a lot less than you would need to hit your limit.

Comment: I really hope so because when I launch it, the last thing I want is a big bill or failure to load data for users because I exceeded the limit. Thanks again mate for the support